# VS Additional Dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, configuration

In VS, I have added additional dependency as default so that it could be added automatically whenever I create new project.

However now I don't want to use this.

I'm trying to delete it but I don't know how.

I have no idea how I added this to default.

Anybody know how to delete or add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the solution explorer select your project
2. Right click on your project and select Project Dependencies. Note that the Project Dependencies option is only available in a solution with more than one project, which is your case I believe.
   [image]
3. On the Dependencies tab, select a project from the Project drop-down menu.
4. In the Depends on field, clear the check boxes beside any other projects that are no longer dependencies of this project.

For more details, visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx

Comment: My solution has only a single project and is inheriting its dependencies from project default. Every time I create a project, I have to uncheck the 'inheirit from parent or project defaults' button. I want to remove the dll I am not using now so that I can work with the project right away after creating the project.